# WordPress custom post type category order

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I'm looking for a way to manually reorder the category list for custom post types,
are there any plug-ins that already do this?

I can probably code my own, but I'm not sure where to start, can you add custom fields to the categories that can be used to order them?

Anything to point me in the right direction would be great!

---

### EDIT [resolved]

After a bit more digging I uncovered this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-my-category-order-custom-taxonomy-order-and-code-improvements

Which linked to this:

http://snipplr.com/view/48599/mycategoryorder-custom-taxonomy-mod/

and once you change line 51 to you custom taxonomy type it works like a charm, eg:

```
$tax = ($_GET['mytax'])? $_GET['mytax'] : 'category';
```

becomes

```
$tax = ($_GET['mytax'])? $_GET['mytax'] : 'my_custom_taxonomy';
```

works perfectly with 'Types' plugin linked by @Ajay Patel, cheers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes. See the part where it says "EDIT [resolved]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to get you question perfectly.
But use this plugin [Types - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/)

Types makes it easy to customize the WordPress admin. Define your own content using custom post types and custom taxonomy. Redesign editing screens using custom fields.

Comment: It looks like a nice framework for custom post types, I tested it out and unfortunately there's no way to reorder the categories. I'm looking for some way to rearrange the categories in a custom order instead of by date or by name.